# Is it possible to have multiple views in a menu item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-imageview, android-menu

I'm trying to do something like the mockup I drew below. I have menu items but on each I want one image view and one text view. All I'm seeing is title and icon attributes in the menu items which don't do the job.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the standard Android widgets (Menu, MenuItem, etc), then **no**, this is not possible.

However, you could create your own floating view that looked just like a standard Android menu, and then do whatever you want.